# Как можно реализовать подобное с помощью библиотеке telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мы пишем в чат любой звук, он нам присылает звуки зебры, с парсингом звуков с сайта нет проблем, а вот как конкретно отправлять с сайта звук в таком формате как на скрине выше [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
У меня получается только вот так, как сделать это без ссылки или есть ещё способы, как это можно сделать, может нужно сохранять звук на сервер и с него отправлять пользователю?

Comment: Ну если попробывать отправить как голосовое сообщние.

Comment: Получилось, спасибо